# The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. but is supported by linq-to-sql

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

A project just switched from linq-to-sql to linq-to-entities, and now I get the error

```
The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
```

for this line:

```
var a = db.Table.Single(d => d.Date == dates[0]);
```

(Fixing it in this particular case is easy, as in

```
var firstDate = dates[0];
var a = db.Table.Single(d => d.Date == firstDate);
```

)

But why does this work in linq-to-sql but not in linq-to-entities?
Did they make linq-to-entities worse than linq-to-sql?
What am I missing?

Comment: LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities are developed entirely separately, there is no relevant shared code here. It requires extra support in LINQ to SQL for something that at first glance doesn't make sense (it looks like you're trying to pass `dates` as an array parameter, and have the server read the first element), so I'm guessing it isn't very commonly used and for that reason was simply never considered for LINQ to Entities. As this is a guess, I will refrain from posting it as an answer.

Comment: It looks like a bug to me. The expression tree should be resolved down to simplest expressions first, before translating to SQL. This is essentially what @dontomaso is doing by pre-evaluating dates[0], but should not have to do it manually (especially for such a simple expression).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because L2E just tries to translate your query to a sql command. So, any additional things (methods like .ToString(), and other things which can't be translated to SQL) leads to that exception.

However, L2S like linq to objects implements IEnumerable. So, the goal of them is different: L2E to translate linq queries to sql commands, L2O to work with in-memory IEnumerable objects, and L2S to model and work with a database.

Now, if want to be able to use your L2S queries in your EF project(using L2E), you should first convert your data retrieved from you DbContext to IEnumerable:

```
var a = db.Table.AsEnumerable().Single(d => d.Date == dates[0]); 
// or any other methods...
```

Comment: Brings all data from database to memory is not idea. Proper way is copy value to a variable. `var date = dates[0]; var a = db.Table.Single(d => d.Date == date);`